# Redirect URLs to others

Tags: centos, networking

I was asking me if I can redirect all my system request from `server1.com/service1` to `server2.com/service1`..

This is my situation. I have a web application in my main server (**mainserver.com**), Then I have 3 servers with a serie of rest services, by example:

```
mainserver.com -> web application

serviceserver1.com/createUser
serviceserver2.com/createUser
serviceserver3.com/createUser
```

It's very common that serviceservers are down, then we have to change the service URLs to another server and restar our app (We can't change the app behaivour)

Well, I was thinking about something like host redirections or something that works like these, but only in URL level, no host level.

Comment: Does the "web application" run on "mainserver.com" and make requests to "serviceserverX.com" or does the request for "serviceserverX.com" come a client device? If "mainserver.com" is making the request you can edit `/etc/hosts` which should be read per request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nginx for that:
first you have to configure and upstream:

```
upstream web {
  server serviceserver1.com
  server serviceserver2.com
  server serviceserver3.com
}
```

Then what you're looking for are: `proxy_next_upstream` and `proxy_connect_timeout`.

Try this:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass              $scheme://web;
        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_next_upstream     error timeout invalid_header http_500;
        proxy_connect_timeout   2;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For 
        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```